# Installing Exchange 2003 on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003

I am attempting to install Exchange Server 2003 on Windows Server 2003 R2. I have installed all of the prerequisites as far as I can tell. When I run the install program and try to tell it to do a typical install it comes up with an error message saying that the NNTP component of IIS is either not installed or disabled. I have installed the component and check in the IIS management console to make sure it is enabled, which it is. Any ideas?

--Kyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to check is that the NNTP service is installed and running in the services MMC. If its not there it may not have installed correctly. Go back into add windows components, untick NNTP and remove it, re-boot the server and then re-install it. Then confirm the service is started.

Comment: +1, exactly what I would do.

Comment: Just needed the restart apparently, I feel stupid now. I was hoping I wouldn't have to restart the server during the install. Thanks for the help!